# How to get the changed content (string) after first loop iteration to be used in next iteration in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a list of strings where a specified part should be replaced with another.

String_01:

```
UNH+000000'
BGM+ZLI+000000'
DTM+3:20210430:102'
RFF+AFL:000000'
RFF+CO:186577666'
RFF+PK:000000'
MOA+125:000000'
MOA+150:000000'
UNT+26+000000'
```

String_02:

```
UNH+000000'
BGM+ZLI+000000'
DTM+3:20210430:102'
RFF+AFL:000000'
RFF+CO:186578112'
RFF+PK:000000'
MOA+125:000000'
MOA+150:000000'
UNT+26+000000'
```

String_03:

```
UNH+000000'
BGM+ZLI+000000'
DTM+3:20210430:102'
RFF+AFL:000000'
RFF+CO:186601036'
RFF+PK:000000'
MOA+125:000000'
MOA+150:000000'
UNT+66+000000'
```

Then I have a dictionary key containing the things what should be replaced and value has the new value.

```
&{PO_PAIRS}             186577666=4500000842    186578112=4500000843    186601036=4500000844
```

Now I iterate through every string with the dictionary. If the dictionary key is found from the string, it's changed to dictionary value.

```
NewString
    [Arguments]             ${string}
    FOR     ${key}      IN  @{PO_PAIRS}
        ${value} =             Get from dictionary     ${PO_PAIRS}        ${key}
        ${changed_string} =    Replace string          ${string}          ${key}  ${value}
    END
    [Return]                   ${changed_string}
```

The problem is that after first iteration of the loop, the `${changed_string}` should be the starting point for the next iteration instead of `${string}`. Is there some way to set the `${changed_string}` for the next iterations in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> problem is that after first iteration of the loop, the `${changed_string}` should be the starting point for the next iteration instead of `${string}`

Yep, in every iteration you're redefining `${changed_string}`, and thus at the end it's `${string}` with just the last change.
Don't use an intermediate variable, reassign the replaced string to `${string}`, and return it:

```
NewString
    [Arguments]             ${string}
    FOR     ${key}      IN  @{PO_PAIRS}
        ${value} =     Get from dictionary     ${PO_PAIRS}        ${key}
        ${string} =    Replace string          ${string}          ${key}  ${value}
    END
    [Return]                   ${string}
```